# Where is the default location path for a postgresql database of a Ruby-on Rails app (Ubuntu dedicated server) ? And how to visualize datas in csv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, path, visualization

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I'm runing a Ruby-on Rails app on a dedicated server (with Ubuntu).

1. I wonder where is the `default location path` for a postgresql database ?
2. And what `tool` do you recommend `to visualize` the datas ?

=> maybe extract database tables to a **csv file**, then open it in Excel ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Visualize data can be in many form, the paid and good apps should be tableau, power BI, even if you want to use Excel/LibreOffice Pivot table also possible (as nowdays spreadsheet could query data to DB), other than that if it's web based, use chartjs, etc etc...

Comment: Simple Search Engine query will give you https://askubuntu.com/questions/617751/default-location-of-postgresql-when-installing-through-apt-get, I think it's better to search first, then ask, as you don't talk about code, it should be out of stack overflow, based on community guideline.

Answer (score 0):

Default location is here :

```
/var/lib/postgresql/{version_number}/main
```